# Regex: Repeat pattern n times, with variation on final repetition

Tags: javascript, .net, regex

I have a regular expression which is intended to match a specific syntax, *n* times, with a pipe (|) following each occurrence, except for the final occurrence. Currently, my pattern is along the lines of `(pattern)\|{3}`, but this doesn't satisfy the requirement that there is no trailing pipe. Is there anyway I can accomplish this *without repeating* `(pattern)`? The best solution I can think of is `(pattern)\|{2}(pattern)`.

**Valid Example:**

> *|401|[2-10]

**Invalid Example:**

> *|401|[2-10]|

The value of `(pattern)` is extraneous to answering my specific question, but for completeness, here it is in its current form: `(?:(?:((\*)|(\[[\w+ ]\-[\w+ ]\])|(\d+)))\|){3}`

*Edit*

This is being consumed within .NET and JavaScript.

Comment: could you provide the real example?

Comment: Again, I don't think it's super critical to the actual question, but this would be an example of a valid input: `[1-2]|*|254`

Comment: `The best solution I can think of is (pattern)\|{2}(pattern).` It is the best solution in my opinion - you don't have to care about dealing with unmatched number of pattern and delimiter. To prevent repetition, just use string concatenation to build the pattern.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a simple solution, if you're matching the entire input string:

```
(?:pattern(?:\|(?!$)|$)){3}
```

Which means: match your *pattern* followed by:

- either `\|(?!$)`: a pipe *not* followed by the end of the string
- or `$` the end of the string

3 times.

---

For your specific pattern, this would be:

```
^(?:(?:((\*)|(\[[\w+ ]\-[\w+ ]\])|(\d+)))(?:\|(?!$)|$)){3}
```

I also prefixed the pattern with `^`, since this solution works only if you match the entire input anyway.

Comment: but this matches the one which have trailing `|`

Comment: I went with this solution as it was easier (for me) to understand. Thank you!